# Unable to Connect Trezor

Tags: wallet-recovery, trezor

My trezor worked fine until the other day it wouldn't connect.  I tried myehterwallet, trezor app in Chrome, and the trezor.io site--nothing.  I've tried using different cables, different computers, different usb ports and even followed the trezor instructions for emergency reset.  Nothing is working to open my Trezor and allow access to my currency stored on it.

Comment: I don't see any question. We can't help you fix broken hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You should have your Trezor recovery card with 24 words you have written down. With these 24 words (the recovery seed) you can access your coins without a Trezor. Here is an [explanation](https://trezor.io/troubleshooter/#26).

If this doesn't help you might want to contact [Trezor support](https://trezor.io/support/).